# SQL statement to select number of tickets opened per user per company

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables: Company, SR_Service (holds ticket information) and Contacts.

I'd like to pull the following for any given month: Company Name, Tickets Opened divided by number of users in each company, Month

e.g.

- XYZ Ltd, 0.13, January
- ABC Ltd, 0.07, January
- DEF Ltd, 0.20, January

etc.

I've been able to get this information for one company by using this query (company_recID is used as the company identifier):

```
SELECT 
co.Company_Name,
(CAST((COUNT(SR_Service_RecID)) AS FLOAT)     /    
  (SELECT count(Contact_RecID)
   FROM Contact 
   WHERE Company_RecID = 2215)) AS 'Tickets Per User'
FROM SR_Service s
LEFT JOIN company as co 
  on s.company_recid = co.company_recid
LEFT JOIN Contact as con 
  on co.Company_RecID = con.Contact_RecID
WHERE s.date_entered BETWEEN '2014-12-26 13:36:00' and '2015-01-02 13:36:00'
AND  co.Company_RecID = 2215
GROUP BY co.Company_Name
```

However, I can't seem to get the information in the format as listed in my example above. I really don't want to put a new ID around 250 times!

Thanks in advance
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it as `correlated subquery`

```
SELECT co.Company_Name,
       ( Cast(( Count(SR_Service_RecID) ) AS FLOAT) / (SELECT Count(Contact_RecID)
                                                       FROM   Contact cc
                                                       WHERE  cc.Company_RecID = co.Company_RecID) ) AS 'Tickets Per User',
       Datename(mm, date_entered) [month]
FROM   SR_Service s
       LEFT JOIN company AS co
              ON s.company_recid = co.company_recid
       LEFT JOIN Contact AS con
              ON co.Company_RecID = con.Contact_RecID
WHERE  s.date_entered BETWEEN '2014-12-26 13:36:00' AND '2015-01-02 13:36:00'
GROUP  BY co.Company_Name,
          Datename(mm, date_entered)
```

Comment: I like it even more now :P

Comment: You sir/Madam, are a genius!  I'm more than prepared to mark your answer as correct, and feel free to ignore this as you have already helped me out massively, but I'm curious to know why this fixes the problem. I'm relatively new to SQL

Comment: err.. perhaps I just need to google correlated subquerys! Let have a read up on that